# Purification of compound containing dicarboxylic acid and amine

Tags: organic-chemistry

The prep-LC in my lab is broken and I need to urgently purify [my compound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/breeX.jpg) which contains two carboxylic acid groups, one amine, and one amide bond. This compound was synthesized with [the scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/breeX.jpg) and it did dissolve well in the reaction solvents, which are DMF and water, but it does not seem to dissolve in any other organic solvents... I am having a difficulty in finding out a suitable TLC eluent system because of this issue. Can anybody please advise me what to do?

Comment: Do you have access to reverse-phase TLC plates?

Comment: @Waylander I guess I can buy. I am struggling to find a correct solvent system that can dissolve the compound.

Comment: Have you tried these systems for very polar compounds
    1 - 10% NH 4OH in MeOH solution as your polar solvent: try 1-10% of this mixture in dichloromethane.
   2-  EBAW: EtOAc/butanol/HOAc/H 2O in a 80/10/5/5 ratio